# Creating a Bruteforce Program which shuffles through random non-recurring numbers. Receiving a ValueError - unsure why?

Tags: python, random, error-handling, shuffle, brute-force

A while back some great people on this site helped me create this code which essentially bruteforces through numbers 0-999999 and tells me how long it took to find the password. Problem is, I need the program to go through these numbers randomly (ie. not from lowest to highest.)

This is the original code which works (but does not go through numbers randomly):

```
import random

digits = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
s = [''.join([a, b, c, d, e, f]) for a in digits for b in digits for c in     digits for d in digits for e in digits for f in digits]
random.shuffle(s)
real_password = '123456'
i = 0

for code in s:
    if code == real_password:
        print()
        print('The password is: ', code)
        break
    else:
        i += 1
        print(i, ' failures', end='\r')
```

And here is the code which I tweaked slightly but isn't working:

```
import datetime as dt
import random

digits = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
s = [''.join([a, b, c, d, e, f]) for a in digits for b in digits for c in     digits for d in digits for e in digits for f in digits]
random.shuffle(s)

Password4 = 999999

def crack_password():
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    for n in s:
        password_guess = '{0:04d}'.format(n)
        if password_guess == str(Password4):
            end = dt.datetime.now()
            print("Password found: {} in {} seconds".format(password_guess, end - start))
            break

guesses = crack_password()
```

This is what my console looks like (the errors that appear) when I try to run it:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Math IA/Trials.6.2.1py.py", line 19, in 
    guesses = crack_password()
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Math IA/Trials.6.2.1py.py", line 13, in crack_password
    password_guess = '{0:04d}'.format(n)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks everyone for your help! I'm still somewhat of a beginner so forgive me if this is a dumb question :)

Comment: Cast that `n` you are trying to pass as argument to `format` into `int`, perhaps? `'{0:04d}'.format(int(n))`

Comment: @Slayther thanks so much ! works now :)

Comment: Why do you need to go through them randomly?

Answer (score 0):

replace the 0:04d with 0.04s and your error should be gone... you tell the machine to expect a double number (d) where you give it a string instead

Comment: Thanks for your response! Tried your solution but unfortunately I got this error:  line 13, in crack_password
    password_guess = '{0:04s}'.format(n)
ValueError: '=' alignment not allowed in string format specifier     Luckily the other commenters solution worked, so I'm all good now!